# Hazelcast error in t com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass

Tags: java, heap-memory, hazelcast

My application uses Hazelcast and after a time working with it gives me an error in this library.
The Log is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:124)
at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:97)
at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$1.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:113)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:196)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:309)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:439)
at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.ConfigCheck.readData(ConfigCheck.java:215)
at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.JoinMessage.readData(JoinMessage.java:80)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:111)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:39)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:309)
at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:439)
at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.MulticastService.receive(MulticastService.java:155)
```

Comment: My configuration is:
  
<group>
        <name>app</name>
        <password>1234</password>
    </group>
    
    <!--client properties-->
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.connection.timeout">10000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.retry.count">6</property>
    </properties>
     <network>
        <port auto-increment="true">5107</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false" />
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <members>127.0.0.1:5701</members>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>

Comment: It might be helpful to show the important parts of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your webapp is shutting down since the WebappClassLoader throws IllegalStateException, therefore it is not a real Hazelcast problem. Possibly you try to re-deploy?